# RabbitMQ How to set up producer and client environment?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have fresh installation of RabbitMQ on a linux/ubuntu server. Lets say the server works under superserver.com domain. What steps should I take right after installing it, because I can not connect to it from remote consumer/producer ? Do I have to change something in configuration file ? I'm asking because I don't have access to the server and I need an instruction to tell admin what to do next.

Another thing that bothers me. Do I have to install RabbitMQ on clients too or is it just necessary for clusters ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally !

After some research I found a solution to this. I'm writing it here so everyone can see it.
I had to change AMQP protocol version. By default it's set to AMQP 0-9 but RabbitMQ works with: **AMQP 0-8** ! So this is how it should look for c#:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.HostName = "your.hostname.com";
factory.Protocol = RabbitMQ.Client.Protocols.AMQP_0_8;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You must be using an older version of RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be anything you need to do for a default install to connect to the default virtual host with user id: "guest" and password: "guest".

By default, the installer doesn't install the [Management plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html), which you'll want to install to debug and manage things more easily.  In linux, just run the following:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Verify that its up and running by going to the following URL:

http://superserver.com:55672/mgmt/

After that, I would recommend you creating an "admin" user either from the command line or through the management web site.

```
rabbitmqctl.bat add_user admin [admin password]
rabbitmqctl.bat set_permissions -p / admin ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

I would then delete the "guest" user, or at minimum change the password.  From there, you should be able to test out a client connection and log into the management site to see if your messages are getting published.

For the client side, you just need to have a RabbitMQ client library, not rabbit itself.  This is basically a library that knows how to issue ampq commands over a TCP/IP connection.
If you're doing Java, you can download the Java client [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html).

Comment: Also, make sure tcp ports 5672 (for amqp) and 55672 (for management) are open

Comment: So far I didn't manage to find a working solution. I tried creating a new user. Ports are open, telnet connection to port 5672 is accepted. I also installed RabbitMQ on Windows 7 and it works like a charm under localhost from the same machine. Im using .NET library and while connecting I receive exception: "None of the specified endpoints were reachable".

Which settings should be passed to ConnectionFactory class ? I tried every possible combination but still no luck :(